# Commands return data

Tags: php, oop, laravel, design-patterns

I'm trying to clean up some of my controllers by moving the functionality from the controller methods to reusable commands that I can just pass on to a command bus. As I've understood, though, a command is not supposed to return data (or did I misunderstand something?). But how else would you suggest for the controller to act on the outcome of the command?

For instance I have a Create endpoint in my ClientController. The controller method dispatches a CreateClient command, and then I'd like to redirect the user to the new Client's edit page. Something like

```
class ClientController extends Controller
{
    public function create($request)
    {
        try {
            $this->dispatch(new CreateClient(/*get something from the request to pass*/));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }

        $client = ...;
        $this->redirect('/client/' . $client->id);
    }
}
```

If the creation failed I can throw an exception, which can be handled by the controller. I could of course create a method in my ClientRepository to get the newest created Client, but that seems error prone. But how would you suggest that I got a hold of the newly created client?

**Edit:**

At the end of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fbSYZFZCFS0 they discus this actual problem. Their main suggestions are using UUIDs so the ID can be generated by the controller, or using an asynchronous method to poll for the new item.

They also mention the possibility of using event listeners, but argue that it's an anti-pattern in PHP.

I'm still undecided on how I'll prefer to do it.

Comment: Perhaps you could listen to a domain event?`DomainEvents.when<ClientCreated>(...)
$this->dispatch(...)`

Comment: In practice the client code usually generates the AR id, so you wouldn't need to return it.

Comment: I'm not sure which part of this you refer to as the client code. I wouldn't expect the browser to generate the ID.

Comment: Echoing @plalx, I use events.

Comment: @Jarlskov You could generate it from the controller using an application service, but if your ids are GUIDs I think that it wouldn't matter if the browser generated it.

Comment: Currently I'm just using regular auto-increment IDs, which means I can't generate them from the frontend since I'll need the database to do it.
I might look into whether the framework I use allows me to listen to events from the controller. I don't think it does, and it feels a bit strange to me, but it might make sense when I try it out.